# How do I create an extraction Formula to isolate a numeric customer ID?

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I have these two formulas isolating the customer ID and [Humcrypt], but I just want the customer ID, I can create a new column and get the numeric value isolated. Trying to do it without creating extra columns. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
=RIGHT(A11,LEN(A11) - MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, A11&"0123456789")) -7)
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,LEFT(A2,MIN(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2),""))+6),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot please post a markdown data, so that anyone can copy and post the solution for your need

Comment: Are you just trying to get the numeric values out of the string, or only the digits before the ID? Also other rules of your data would probably be meaningful. What is the specific rule as in length of data, circumstances of data to omit?

Comment: Few Ways you can give a try not knowing your excel version but this should work, if you need those 6 numbers `=IFERROR(TEXT(LOOKUP(10^8,MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","x"),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-5)),6)+0),"000000"),"")
`

Answer (score 2):

If customer ID is always at end followed by '[Humcrypt]' and the same length then try:

```
=--LEFT(RIGHT(A1,17),6)
```

If not always the same length ID then try:

```
=--TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1," ",-2)," ")
```

Or:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]/preceding::*[1]")
```

---

If customer ID is always 6 digits and always followed but could be anywhere in the string then try:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length()=6][.*0=0]")
```

Note that you can alter the xpath to your needs. For example; if length is equal or larger than 6 then use `//s[string-length()>=6][.*0=0]`

Comment: I love filiterxml except it doesn't work for Excel on the web :/ Or macs (but who cares about those users...)

Answer (score 2):

Here is few other alternatives,

[image]

---

• in cell `B1`

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,--MID(A1,ROW($A$1:$A$102),6),1),"")
```

---

• in cell `B2`

```
=MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$202),6),""))
```

Also for this we can follow as suggested by **[pgSystemTester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11732320/pgsystemtester)** Sir, if you are in MS365

```
=MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2),1),6),""))
```

---

• in cell `B3`

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(LOOKUP(10^8,MID(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","x"),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A3)-5)),6)+0),"000000"),"")*1
```

---

For this one we can replace the use `INDIRECT()` function with `INDEX()` function as suggested by **[SCOTT CRANER](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir, best to avoid a `VOLATILE` Function

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(LOOKUP(10^8,MID(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","x"),ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A3)-5)),6)+0),"000000"),"")*1
```

---

• in cell `B4`

```
=CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))
```

---

• Here is one more, way to do,

```
=MAX(IFERROR(--TEXTSPLIT(A1,," "),0))
```

---

Comment: Friendly suggestion... use `sequence` based on length of string rather than using a row hack. Example... of revising your formula `=MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2),1),6),""))` This also avoid using `indirect` a volatile function.

Comment: Sir I agree with you, and second your suggestion, but I am not sure whether OP is in MS365 or not, so shared that version, I agree that hack is very bad it just freezes excel.

Comment: instead of `ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A3)-5)` you can do `ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A3)-5))`  then it is not volatile.

Answer (score 2):

This works based on leveraging the formula you already have. It's a little long, but it works on on all versions of Excel as well as google sheets, and is dynamic for length of string.

```
=LEFT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1),""))+6),"")),  
FIND(" ",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1),""))+6),""))))
```